# Spring security5: LogoutFilter is fired before OAuth2 check

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

We're migrating a large project that used spring security 3.2 with xml configuration to a current spring boot stack with spring-security 5.0 and a programmatic configuration.
The old logout worked nicely by registering the logout-success-handler as a custom filter at the end of the filter chain. 
The relevant part of the old xml-configuration:

```
[...]
<http pattern="/oauth/(users|clients)/.*" request-matcher="regex" create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/users/revoke" method="POST" access="#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_CLIENT') and (hasRole('ROLE_USER') or #oauth2.isClient())" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll()" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    <expression-handler ref="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
    <custom-filter ref="revokeFilter" before="LAST" />
</http>

[...]
<bean id="revokeFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="com.company.management.authorization.oauth2.RevokeSuccessHandler" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/oauth/users/revoke" />
</bean>
[...]
```

This resulted in the following filter chain:

```
Security filter chain: [
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
  LogoutFilter
]
```

When I configure the resource server now by adding the logout success handler this way:

```
@Override
public void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception
{
    http.regexMatcher( "/oauth/(users|clients)/.*" )
        .anonymous( ).disable( ).authorizeRequests( )
        .regexMatchers( HttpMethod.POST, "/oauth/users/revoke" )
        .access( "#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_CLIENT') and (hasRole('ROLE_USER') or #oauth2.isClient())" )
        .antMatchers( "/**" ).denyAll( )
        .and( ).sessionManagement( ).sessionCreationPolicy( SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS )
        .and( ).csrf( ).disable( ).exceptionHandling( )
        .accessDeniedHandler( this.oAuth2AccessDeniedHandler )
        .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor( this.oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint,new AntPathRequestMatcher( "/**" ) )
        .and( ).logout( ).logoutUrl( "/oauth/users/revoke" ).logoutSuccessHandler( revokeSuccessHandler( ) );
}
```

The logout handler is fired, before the OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter is applied and therefore no authentication was done. The filter chain then looks like this:

```
Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]
```

The authentication object in the logout success handler is null and the logic in the handler (with some additional checks based on the given authentication object) does not work anymore.
If I remove the logout success handler, OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter checks are correctly done and the authentication works as intended (but then, the logout is missing, of course). 
If I change the logic in the logout handler and strip out the token from the Authorization header of the request, i could load the authorization from the token store and then implement the access checks manually again, but that does not seem to be the way it should be done...

So, the main problem is, that the LogoutFilter is set before the OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter in the filter chain and I couldn't find a way to change the order.
I tried to set the property `security.oauth2.resource.filter-order` to 3 but this didn't help. I also tried different values for the `@Order` annotation, but with no luck.
I suppose that the way to go may be to add a custom-filter of type LogoutFilter after the OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter (or "before last", like it was done in the xml configuration) by doing something like `and( ).addFilterAfter( revokeFilterBean(), OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.class )`
But I cannot instantiate the necessary LogoutFilter class, as it needs the List of LogoutHandlers as constructor argument, which I don't have (passing null leads to an error and trying to autowire won't work too).

So, whats the right way to achieve the correct filter order?